# Count Values in a column and add the result next to the column in a new one sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
A Home Away 
D Lisa Jill
D Jack Andre
C Jack Kirk
C Jane Jill
```

and want to get the following result

```
A Home Away Count
D Lisa Jill 1
D Jack Andre 2
C Jack Kirk 2
C Jane Jill  1
```

is there a way to do so in sql?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```sql
select 
     "A", "Home", "Away", 
     count(*) over (partition by "Home") as "Count"
from _table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
WITH table_counts AS (
  SELECT
    Home,
    count(*) as table_count
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY Home
)
SELECT
  t1.A,
  t1.Home,
  t1.Away,
  t2.table_count as Count
FROM your_table t1
JOIN table_counts t2 ON t2.Home = t1.Home;
```